# Problemas com horário de verão (ao retornar timestamp) salvo banco de dados

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou tendo dor de cabeça depois do dia 19 de outubro, como era de praxe o horário de verão, e esse ano não houve, alguns clientes ao realizarem algumas tarefas no meu sistema de frequência escolar, ao salvar uma data que é salva no padrão timtestamp, alguns datas foram salvas com 1 hora a menos, exemplo utilizando o epochconverter:

Timestamp no bd está = 1573610400
GMT: Wednesday, 13 November 2019 02:00:00
Your time zone: Quarta-feira, 13 de Novembro de 2019 às 00:00:00 GMT-02:00 DST

Enquanto o timestamp deveria ser = 1573614000
GMT: Wednesday, 13 November 2019 03:00:00
Your time zone: Quarta-feira, 13 de Novembro de 2019 às 01:00:00 GMT-02:00 DST

Esse erro só aconteceu em alguns dias dos meses de outubro e novembro após o dia 19 e outubro. Por isso o sistema não retorna a frequência do aluno no dia.

Minha dúvida é, "Tem como criar uma função no php que busque o timestamp do dia ignorando a hora ou timezone? Meu código usado:

```
$attendance = $this->db->get_where('attendance', array(
  'section_id' => $section_id,
  'class_id' => $class_id,
  'year' => $running_year,
  'timestamp' => $timestamp,
  'student_id' => $row->student_id
  ))->result_array();


 foreach ($attendance as $row1) :
  $month_dummy = gmdate('d', $row1['timestamp']);

  if ($i == $month_dummy) {
   $status = $row1['status'];
  }
```

Comment: Timestamp não possui fuso horário, se gravou um considerando fuso horário então gravou errado, acho que a melhor solução é consertar o dado no DB. Timestamp deve ser UTC sempre.

Comment: @Maniero também não entendi o porque isso aconteceu, já estou convertendo no BD, grato.

Comment: Aconteceu porque você gravou errado.

Comment: Exatamente como eles disseram, acabou gravando errado os dados no db, você poderá atualizar corretamente a coluna afetada com um UPDATE, mas antes disso, sugiro que altere no arquivo de configuração do php (php.ini) ou no próprio código o timezone, estou utilizando America/Fortaleza por não ser afetado pelo horário de verão